# Typescript Cobertura coverage report

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, cobertura

Anyone know command line option to change Cobertura coverage output name via commandline?
Currently I am getting coverage report file cobertura-coverage.xml in coverage folder with below command.I want to rename coverage report file name from cmd.
Command: npx jest --coverageReporters=cobertura

Example: in python we use --cov-report=xml:$1 command line option
Where =xml is type of report and $1 is argument in pipeline.
Coverage report should be renamed as per name of $1.

Comment: There is a coverageDirectory option that you can pass in from the command line. Would that solve your issue?

Comment: Nope didn't worked.

Comment: You might just need to have a separate step somewhere that renames the file manually. I don't think you can rename the file from jest, you can only change the output directory.